# Parsing complex response i.e response having an array inside another array from SOAP in Android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am trying to parse the SOAP in Android by following code:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetSeatLayout";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetSeatLayout";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Object>  strAreaCategoryCode = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  intAreaNumber = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  strClass = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  objArrseatInfo = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  intExceptioncode = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  ScreenId = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  StatusId = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  TicketRate = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  Charge = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  OtherCharge = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  TotalCharge = new ArrayList<Object>(); 

        ArrayList<Object>  strRow = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  intSeat = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  intSeatID = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  rowseatStatus = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
        ArrayList<Object>  hasCurrentOrder = new ArrayList<Object>(); 


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        Log.e("","request"+request);

        String strCinemaCode ="0002";
        long lngSessionId=103286;
        String strShowClass = "EXECUTIVE";
        long lngNoOfTickets = 1;
        int intBookId = 0;
        long UniqueReqI = 0;
        String SeatSelected = ",O_14";
        int intAggregatorID = 1; //1-fame / 2-Inox
        String strCTransId  = "20002070519";

        PropertyInfo strCinemaCode1 =new PropertyInfo();
        strCinemaCode1.setName("strCinemaCode");
        strCinemaCode1.setValue(strCinemaCode);
        strCinemaCode1.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strCinemaCode1);

        PropertyInfo lngSessionId1 =new PropertyInfo();
        lngSessionId1.setName("lngSessionId");
        lngSessionId1.setValue(lngSessionId);
        //lngSessionId1.setType(long.class);
        request.addProperty(lngSessionId1);

        PropertyInfo strShowClass1 =new PropertyInfo();
        strShowClass1.setName("strShowClass");
        strShowClass1.setValue(strShowClass);
        strShowClass1.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strShowClass1);

        PropertyInfo lngNoOfTickets1 =new PropertyInfo();
        lngNoOfTickets1.setName("lngNoOfTickets");
        lngNoOfTickets1.setValue(lngNoOfTickets);
        //lngNoOfTickets1.setType(long.class);
        request.addProperty(lngNoOfTickets1);

        PropertyInfo intBookId1 =new PropertyInfo();
        intBookId1.setName("intBookId");
        intBookId1.setValue(intBookId);
        intBookId1.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(intBookId1);

        PropertyInfo UniqueReqI1 =new PropertyInfo();
        UniqueReqI1.setName("UniqueReqI");
        UniqueReqI1.setValue(UniqueReqI);
       // UniqueReqI1.setType(long.class);
        request.addProperty(UniqueReqI1);

        PropertyInfo SeatSelected1 =new PropertyInfo();
        SeatSelected1.setName("SeatSelected");
        SeatSelected1.setValue(SeatSelected);
        SeatSelected1.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strCinemaCode1);

        PropertyInfo intAggregatorID1 =new PropertyInfo();
        intAggregatorID1.setName("intAggregatorID");
        intAggregatorID1.setValue(intAggregatorID);
        intAggregatorID1.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(intAggregatorID1);

        PropertyInfo strCTransId1 =new PropertyInfo();
        strCTransId1.setName("strCTransId");
        strCTransId1.setValue(strCTransId);
        strCTransId1.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(strCTransId1);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


            Log.e("","response:"+response.toString());

            String []categories = new String [response.getPropertyCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(i);

                strAreaCategoryCode.add(pii.getProperty(0));
                Log.e(""," strAreaCategoryCode= "+ strAreaCategoryCode.get(i));

                intAreaNumber.add(pii.getProperty(1));
                Log.e(""," intAreaNumber= "+ intAreaNumber.get(i));

                strClass.add(pii.getProperty(2));
                Log.e(""," strClass= "+ strClass.get(i));

                objArrseatInfo.add(pii.getProperty(3));
                Log.e(""," objArrseatInfo= "+ objArrseatInfo.get(i));

                intExceptioncode.add(pii.getProperty(4));
                Log.e("","intExceptioncode= "+ intExceptioncode.get(i));

                ScreenId.add(pii.getProperty(5));
                Log.e("","ScreenId= "+ ScreenId.get(i));

                StatusId.add(pii.getProperty(6));
                Log.e(""," StatusId= "+ StatusId.get(i));

                TicketRate.add(pii.getProperty(7));
                Log.e(""," TicketRate= "+ TicketRate.get(i));

                Charge.add(pii.getProperty(8));
                Log.e(""," Charge= "+ Charge.get(i));

                OtherCharge.add(pii.getProperty(9));
                Log.e(""," OtherCharge= "+ OtherCharge.get(i));

                TotalCharge.add(pii.getProperty(10));
                Log.e(""," CinemaCode= "+ TotalCharge.get(i));


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("","Error In some connection");
           String response =  e.toString();
           Log.e("",""+response);
        }
    }
}
```

By using the above code I am getting Following response in Logsheet

```
06-05 18:56:22.937: E/(1689):  strAreaCategoryCode= 0000000007
06-05 18:56:22.937: E/(1689):  intAreaNumber= 1
06-05 18:56:22.947: E/(1689):  strClass= SILVER
06-05 18:56:23.027: E/(1689):  objArrseatInfo= anyType{seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=3; intSeatID=3; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=4; intSeatID=4; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=5; intSeatID=5; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=6; intSeatID=6; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=7; intSeatID=7; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=8; intSeatID=8; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=9; intSeatID=9; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=10; intSeatID=10; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=11; intSeatID=11; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=12; intSeatID=12; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=13; intSeatID=13; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=14; intSeatID=14; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=15; intSeatID=15; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=16; intSeatID=16; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=17; intSeatID=17; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=18; intSeatID=18; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=19; intSeatID=19; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=20; intSeatID=20; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=21; intSeatID=21; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=22; intSeatID=22; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=23; intSeatID=23; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=24; intSeatID=24; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=25; intSeatID=25; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=26; intSeatID=26; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=27; intSeatID=27; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=28; intSeatID=28; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=29; intSeatID=29; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=30; intSeatID=30; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=31; intSeatID=31; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=32; intSeatID=32; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=33; intSeatID=33; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; }
06-05 18:56:23.027: E/(1689): intExceptioncode= 0
06-05 18:56:23.038: E/(1689): ScreenId= 0
06-05 18:56:23.038: E/(1689):  StatusId= 0
06-05 18:56:23.038: E/(1689):  TicketRate= 0
06-05 18:56:23.038: E/(1689):  Charge= 0
06-05 18:56:23.057: E/(1689):  OtherCharge= 0
06-05 18:56:23.077: E/(1689):  CinemaCode= 0


06-05 18:56:23.077: E/(1689):  strAreaCategoryCode= 0000000007
06-05 18:56:23.088: E/(1689):  intAreaNumber= 1
06-05 18:56:23.088: E/(1689):  strClass= SILVER
06-05 18:56:23.227: E/(1689):  objArrseatInfo= anyType{seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=4; intSeatID=4; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=5; intSeatID=5; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=6; intSeatID=6; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=7; intSeatID=7; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=8; intSeatID=8; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=11; intSeatID=11; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=12; intSeatID=12; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=13; intSeatID=13; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=14; intSeatID=14; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=15; intSeatID=15; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=16; intSeatID=16; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=17; intSeatID=17; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=18; intSeatID=18; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=19; intSeatID=19; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=20; intSeatID=20; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=21; intSeatID=21; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=22; intSeatID=22; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=23; intSeatID=23; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=24; intSeatID=24; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=25; intSeatID=25; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=28; intSeatID=28; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=29; intSeatID=29; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=30; intSeatID=30; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=31; intSeatID=31; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intRowID=2; intSeat=32; intSeatID=32; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; }; }
06-05 18:56:23.237: E/(1689): intExceptioncode= 0
06-05 18:56:23.249: E/(1689): ScreenId= 0
06-05 18:56:23.249: E/(1689):  StatusId= 0
06-05 18:56:23.258: E/(1689):  TicketRate= 0
06-05 18:56:23.258: E/(1689):  Charge= 0
06-05 18:56:23.278: E/(1689):  OtherCharge= 0
06-05 18:56:23.278: E/(1689):  CinemaCode= 0
06-05 18:56:23.318: E/(1689):  strAreaCategoryCode= 0000000007
06-05 18:56:23.318: E/(1689):  intAreaNumber= 1
06-05 18:56:23.327: E/(1689):  strClass= SILVER
```

and so on..

Now looking to the response Variable objArrseatInfo is also an array which have many variables inside.

I tried to have those variables into another variable but no use. How can I get those variable similar to the main array?

For example

```
variable strAreaCategoryCode is getting value of pii.getProperty(0)
same way strRow should get the value of strRow from objArrseatInfo= anyType{seatInfo=anyType{strRow=B; intSeat=0; intSeatID=0; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false; };
```

I am new to KSoap Library and after trying I am not able to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this codes to hold all the seatInfo objects into a `ArrayList`.

First add the pojo like as follow:

```
public class SeatInfo {
    private String strRow;
    private int intRowId;
    private int intSeat;
    private int intSeatId;
    private String rowseatStatus;
    private boolean hasCurrentOrder;

    public String getStrRow() {
        return strRow;
    }
    public void setStrRow(String strRow) {
        this.strRow = strRow;
    }
    public int getIntRowId() {
        return intRowId;
    }
    public void setIntRowId(int intRowId) {
        this.intRowId = intRowId;
    }
    public int getIntSeat() {
        return intSeat;
    }
    public void setIntSeat(int intSeat) {
        this.intSeat = intSeat;
    }
    public int getIntSeatId() {
        return intSeatId;
    }
    public void setIntSeatId(int intSeatId) {
        this.intSeatId = intSeatId;
    }
    public String getRowseatStatus() {
        return rowseatStatus;
    }
    public void setRowseatStatus(String rowseatStatus) {
        this.rowseatStatus = rowseatStatus;
    }
    public boolean isHasCurrentOrder() {
        return hasCurrentOrder;
    }
    public void setHasCurrentOrder(boolean hasCurrentOrder) {
        this.hasCurrentOrder = hasCurrentOrder;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SeatInfo [strRow=" + strRow + ", intRowId=" + intRowId
                + ", intSeat=" + intSeat + ", intSeatId=" + intSeatId
                + ", rowseatStatus=" + rowseatStatus + ", hasCurrentOrder="
                + hasCurrentOrder + "]";
    }
}
```

And parse:

```
/** ... */

            /** All the SeatInfo objects */
            SoapObject soapSeatInfo = (SoapObject) pii.getProperty(3);

            /** SeatInfo objects count */
            int seatInfoCount = soapSeatInfo.getPropertyCount();

            /** List to hold all the SeatInfo objects after parsing */
            List<SeatInfo> listSeatInfo = new ArrayList<SeatInfo>();

            for (int j = 0; j < seatInfoCount; j++) {
                /** Temp SeatInfo soap object */
                SoapObject soChild = (SoapObject) soapSeatInfo.getProperty(j);

                /** Temp SeatInfo object */
                SeatInfo si = new SeatInfo();

                /** Setting emp SeatInfo objects all properties */
                si.setStrRow(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow"));
                si.setIntRowId(Integer.parseInt(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow")));
                si.setIntSeat(Integer.parseInt(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow")));
                si.setIntSeatId(Integer.parseInt(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow")));
                si.setRowseatStatus(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow"));
                si.setHasCurrentOrder(Boolean.parseBoolean(soChild.getPropertyAsString("strRow")));

                /** Add temp object to the list */
                listSeatInfo.add(si);
            }
            /** ... */
```

Now you have a list that contains all the `SeatInfo` objects, named **listSeatInfo**. And also each of your objArrseatInfo soap object seen like as follow (may be easier to understand)

```
objArrseatInfo= anyType{
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=3; intSeatID=3; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=4; intSeatID=4; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=5; intSeatID=5; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=6; intSeatID=6; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=7; intSeatID=7; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=8; intSeatID=8; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=9; intSeatID=9; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=10; intSeatID=10; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=11; intSeatID=11; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=12; intSeatID=12; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=13; intSeatID=13; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=14; intSeatID=14; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=15; intSeatID=15; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=16; intSeatID=16; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=17; intSeatID=17; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=18; intSeatID=18; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=19; intSeatID=19; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=20; intSeatID=20; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=21; intSeatID=21; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=22; intSeatID=22; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=23; intSeatID=23; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=24; intSeatID=24; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=25; intSeatID=25; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=26; intSeatID=26; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=27; intSeatID=27; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=28; intSeatID=28; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=29; intSeatID=29; rowseatStatus=Available; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=30; intSeatID=30; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=31; intSeatID=31; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=32; intSeatID=32; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
  seatInfo=anyType{
    strRow=A; intRowID=1; intSeat=33; intSeatID=33; rowseatStatus=Sold; hasCurrentOrder=false;
  };
}
```